# Read key properties

Tags: ssh, encryption, openssh, sshd, key-authentication

I have multiple keys (some private, some public) and I want to get information about them (their length, their type, anything else). Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the question tags, I’m assuming you’re asking about SSH keys.

For public keys, you can ask `ssh-keygen`:

```
ssh-keygen -lf /path/to/key.pub
```

This will show you the key type (at the end of the output), its length (at the beginning), and its fingerprint.

For private keys, you can ask `openssl`, but you’ll need to know the type:

```
openssl rsa -text -noout -in /path/to/id_rsa
```

You’ll need to provide the key’s passphrase, if any; you’ll then see the key size and all its contents.

Comment: The openssl command only works on RSA key types, not ED25519. However the ssh-keygen command seems to work OK on private keys of this format.

Comment: Yes, that’s why I mentioned that you need to know the type to use with the `openssl` command ;-).